# Moving data to fit new data model

Tags: deployment, migration

I am about to deploy a new version of an app. The new version has a very different structure to it, with many new custom objects. In some cases a custom object has been split into two separate large custom objects. In other cases there are objects in which sections have been moved over to another already existing object.

My big dilemma is how to properly migrate this data to fit the new data model. In a good amount of cases it will involve moving data from one object to another, and I am not sure how to do that.

Can somebody give me some advice or tips on the best way to approach this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give any specific advice without knowing the actual complexity, but here is something to get started

Back up current data - use Data Loader to Extract all data and keep a back up

You could refresh a sandbox as a backup of Code / Config before starting any deployment.

Have a pictorial representation of how the old data model relates to the new world and use this to cut up the data into csv files so that they can be imported into the new data tables.

Create External Id fields if it will help you relate data from related child tables to parent tables.

Prepare the csv files, data load into new data structure, save mapping files for repeatable loads.

If you have access to a Full Copy Sandbox, refresh it from Production and rehearse the data split / migration before doing it in Production, so you can uncover any runtime gotchas (triggers, workflows, validation rules, the works...)

Comment: Thank you very much techtrekker. I'll take all the advice I can get. btw - I'm guessing you're recommending Data Loader for the job. Is that because it's the most known ? Or do you truly feel it is the best app for the job ? If not, do you happen to have a suggestion for something which you feel would be better for the job ? I'm not saying there is one, just thought I'd ask. Thanks again.

Comment: I have had experience only with (and regularly use) the Apex Data Loader and I find I can do most things with it, including what you're trying to achieve here. However some folks also swear by the Jitterbit Data Loader. Also there are apps like Monarch which let you move data seamlessly between sandboxes.

Comment: I would add that even without Full Sandbox, you can do at least a small trial in a Config Only (up to 300MB of data) to verify the steps.